Getting error in fetching data with Sequelize for Mysql Database (Backend Node.js)
I am using Sequelize ORM with mysql database for nodejs application. Somewhere I am stuck with one api whose job is just to show list based on the queryparam values. Issue is when I am not applying the pagination i.e. url is like
{{url}}/tasks?pagesize=&page=&start=2024-04-01&end=2024-05-13&task_status_id=&priority_id=&search=Dummy

with pagesize and page as empty string then "search" functionality is working fine. But when I add pagesize=10 and size=1 then it is throwing error:
  original: Error: Unknown column 'customer.contact_person_name' in 'where clause'
      at Packet.asError (xxxx/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at Query.execute (xxxx/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (xxxx/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:481:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (xxxx/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (xxxx/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (xxxx/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:545:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:495:3)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:375:5) {
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'customer.contact_person_name' in 'where clause'",
    sql: "SELECT `tasks`.*, `customer`.`id` AS `customer.id`, `customer`.`organization_name` AS `customer.organization_name`, `customer`.`address` AS `customer.address`, `customer`.`latitude` AS `customer.latitude`, `customer`.`longitude` AS `customer.longitude`, `customer`.`contact_person_name` AS `customer.contact_person_name`, `customer`.`contact_person_email` AS `customer.contact_person_email`, `customer`.`contact_person_phone` AS `customer.contact_person_phone`, `customer`.`contact_person_alternate_phone` AS `customer.contact_person_alternate_phone`, `customer`.`fence_id` AS `customer.fence_id`, `customer`.`country_id` AS `customer.country_id`, `customer`.`state_id` AS `customer.state_id`, `customer`.`status` AS `customer.status`, `fence`.`id` AS `fence.id`, `fence`.`title` AS `fence.title`, `fence`.`area` AS `fence.area`, `fence`.`radius` AS `fence.radius`, `employee`.`id` AS `employee.id`, `employee`.`name` AS `employee.name`, `employee`.`personal_email` AS `employee.personal_email`, `task_status`.`id` AS `task_status.id`, `task_status`.`name` AS `task_status.name`, `task_status`.`color_code` AS `task_status.color_code`, `priority`.`id` AS `priority.id`, `priority`.`name` AS `priority.name`, `priority`.`color_code` AS `priority.color_code`, `task_documents`.`id` AS `task_documents.id`, `task_documents`.`task_id` AS `task_documents.task_id`, `task_documents`.`employee_id` AS `task_documents.employee_id`, `task_documents`.`document_type` AS `task_documents.document_type`, `task_documents`.`media_id` AS `task_documents.media_id`, `task_documents->media`.`id` AS `task_documents.media.id`, `task_documents->media`.`name` AS `task_documents.media.name`, `task_documents->media`.`file_name` AS `task_documents.media.file_name`, `task_documents->media`.`mime_type` AS `task_documents.media.mime_type`, `task_documents->media`.`directory` AS `task_documents.media.directory`, `task_documents->media`.`media_size` AS `task_documents.media.media_size`, `task_documents->media`.`disk` AS `task_documents.media.disk`, `task_documents->document_category`.`id` AS `task_documents.document_category.id`, `task_documents->document_category`.`title` AS `task_documents.document_category.title`, `task_documents->document_category`.`prefix` AS `task_documents.document_category.prefix`, `task_documents->document_category`.`storage` AS `task_documents.document_category.storage` FROM (SELECT `tasks`.`id`, `tasks`.`task_custom_id`, `tasks`.`title`, `tasks`.`description`, `tasks`.`customer_id`, `tasks`.`fence_id`, `tasks`.`planned_date`, `tasks`.`task_status_id`, `tasks`.`priority_id`, `tasks`.`employee_id`, `tasks`.`otp_requirement`, `tasks`.`doc_requirement`, `tasks`.`start_of_service_time`, `tasks`.`end_of_service_time`, `tasks`.`created_at` FROM `tasks` AS `tasks` WHERE (`tasks`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (((`tasks`.`id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`task_custom_id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`title` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`description` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`customer_id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`fence_id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`planned_date` LIKE 'Invalid date' OR `tasks`.`task_status_id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`priority_id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`employee_id` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`otp_requirement` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`doc_requirement` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `tasks`.`start_of_service_time` LIKE 'Invalid date' OR `tasks`.`end_of_service_time` LIKE 'Invalid date' OR `customer`.`contact_person_name` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `customer`.`organization_name` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `task_status`.`name` LIKE '%Dummy%' OR `priority`.`name` LIKE '%Dummy%') AND (`tasks`.`planned_date` > '2024-04-01 00:00:00' AND `tasks`.`planned_date` <= '2024-05-14 00:00:00')))) ORDER BY `tasks`.`planned_date` DESC LIMIT 0, 10) AS `tasks` LEFT OUTER JOIN `customers` AS `customer` ON `tasks`.`customer_id` = `customer`.`id` AND (`customer`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `fences` AS `fence` ON `tasks`.`fence_id` = `fence`.`id` AND (`fence`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `employees` AS `employee` ON `tasks`.`employee_id` = `employee`.`id` AND (`employee`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `task_statuses` AS `task_status` ON `tasks`.`task_status_id` = `task_status`.`id` AND (`task_status`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `priorities` AS `priority` ON `tasks`.`priority_id` = `priority`.`id` AND (`priority`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `task_documents` AS `task_documents` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_documents`.`task_id` AND (`task_documents`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `medias` AS `task_documents->media` ON `task_documents`.`media_id` = `task_documents->media`.`id` AND (`task_documents->media`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LEFT OUTER JOIN `document_categories` AS `task_documents->document_category` ON `task_documents`.`document_type` = `task_documents->document_category`.`id` AND (`task_documents->document_category`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) ORDER BY `tasks`.`planned_date` DESC;",
    parameters: undefined


where is the issue? without pagination it is working fine
Below is the schema for tables
Tasks schema:
"use strict";
const {
    Model
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class tasks extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            tasks.belongsTo(models.employees, {
                foreignKey: "employee_id"
            });

            tasks.belongsTo(models.customers, {
                foreignKey: "customer_id"
            });

            tasks.belongsTo(models.fences, {
                foreignKey: "fence_id"
            });

            tasks.belongsTo(models.task_statuses, {
                foreignKey: "task_status_id"
            });

            tasks.belongsTo(models.priorities, {
                foreignKey: "priority_id"
            });

            tasks.hasMany(models.task_documents, {
                foreignKey: "task_id"
            });
        }
    }
    tasks.init({
        task_custom_id: DataTypes.STRING,
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.TEXT,
        customer_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        fence_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        planned_date: DataTypes.DATE,
        task_status_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        priority_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        employee_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        otp_requirement: DataTypes.TINYINT,
        doc_requirement: DataTypes.TINYINT,
        start_of_service_time: DataTypes.DATE,
        end_of_service_time: DataTypes.DATE
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "tasks",
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
        deletedAt: "deleted_at"
    });
    return tasks;
};

Customer table
"use strict";
const {
    Model
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class customers extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            customers.hasMany(models.tasks, {
                foreignKey: "customer_id"
            });

            customers.belongsTo(models.fences, {
                foreignKey: "fence_id"
            });

            customers.belongsTo(models.countries, {
                foreignKey: "country_id"
            });

            customers.belongsTo(models.states, {
                foreignKey: "state_id"
            });
        }
    }
    customers.init({
        organization_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        address: DataTypes.STRING,
        latitude: DataTypes.STRING,
        longitude: DataTypes.STRING,
        contact_person_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        contact_person_email: DataTypes.STRING,
        contact_person_phone: DataTypes.STRING,
        contact_person_alternate_phone: DataTypes.STRING,
        fence_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        country_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        state_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        status: DataTypes.TINYINT
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "customers",
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
        deletedAt: "deleted_at"
    });
    return customers;
};

Fence table
"use strict";
const {
    Model
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class fences extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            fences.hasMany(models.tasks, {
                foreignKey: "fence_id"
            });

            fences.hasMany(models.customers, {
                foreignKey: "fence_id"
            });

            fences.belongsToMany(models.employees, {
                foreignKey: "fence_id",
                through: models.employees_fences,
                as: "employees"
            });
        }
    }
    fences.init({
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        area: DataTypes.STRING,
        radius: DataTypes.TEXT,
        status: DataTypes.TINYINT
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "fences",
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
        deletedAt: "deleted_at"
    });
    return fences;
};

Employee table
"use strict";
const helper = require("../api/helper.js");
const utils = require("../api/utils");
const {
    Model
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class employees extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            employees.belongsTo(models.users, {
                foreignKey: "user_id"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.medias, {
                foreignKey: "profile_img"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.addresses, {
                as: "present_address",
                foreignKey: "present_address_id"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.addresses, {
                as: "permanent_address",
                foreignKey: "permanent_address_id"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.designations, {
                foreignKey: "designation_id"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.departments, {
                foreignKey: "department_id"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.users, {
                as: "reported_to",
                foreignKey: "report_to"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.users, {
                as: "create_by",
                foreignKey: "created_by"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.users, {
                as: "employeeType",
                foreignKey: "user_id"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.users, {
                as: "update_by",
                foreignKey: "updated_by"
            });

            employees.belongsTo(models.users, {
                as: "delete_by",
                foreignKey: "deleted_by"
            });

            employees.hasMany(models.attendances, {
                foreignKey: "employee_id"
            });

            employees.hasMany(models.tasks, {
                foreignKey: "employee_id"
            });

            employees.belongsToMany(models.fences, {
                foreignKey: "employee_id",
                through: models.employees_fences,
                as: "fences"
            });
        }
    }
    employees.init({
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        personal_email: DataTypes.STRING,
        company_email: DataTypes.STRING,
        phone: DataTypes.STRING,
        gender: DataTypes.ENUM(helper.elementsOfArr(utils.constants.genderEnum)),
        date_of_birth: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        is_married: DataTypes.TINYINT,
        profile_img: DataTypes.BIGINT,

        //Address
        present_address_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        permanent_address_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        is_same_address_flag: DataTypes.TINYINT,

        // Employeement Details
        designation_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        department_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,

        user_id: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        status: DataTypes.TINYINT,

        //Who altered
        created_by: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        updated_by: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        deleted_by: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        deleted_at: DataTypes.DATE
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "employees",
        freezeTableName: true,
        paranoid: true,
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
        deletedAt: "deleted_at"
    });
    return employees;
};

my sequelize query:
//Query for fetching all tasks
function checkEndStart(startD, endD, i18next){
    let startDate = moment(startD, "YYYY-MM_DD").startOf("day");
    let endDate =moment(endD, "YYYY-MM_DD").startOf("day");

    //check the endDate and startDate
    if(endDate.isBefore(startDate)) throw new Error(i18next("DATE_END_CANNOT_BE_AHEAD_OF_START"));

    //add 1 date to endDate
    endDate = endDate.add("1", "day");
    
    return {
        startDate,
        endDate
    };
}

function pagination(pagesize, page) {
    const parseSize = parseInt(pagesize);
    const parsePage = parseInt(page);

    return {
        "limit": (parseSize) ? parseSize : null,
        "offset": (page) ? ( parsePage - 1) * parseSize : null,
    };
}

function addSearchCondForAllCol(rawAttributes, search, Op) {
    let condition = Object.keys(rawAttributes).filter(key => !["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"].includes(key)).map(key => {
    return { [key]: { [Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" } };
    });
    
    return condition;
},

getAllTasksForEmployee: async (pagesize, page, start, end, search, task_status_id, priority_id, t, employee_id) => {
        try {
            let condition = { };

            const getPagination = pagination(pagesize, page);
            let getDate = checkEndStart(start, end, t);

            //any values exists for these fields then append it in the main condition object
            if (employee_id) condition = { employee_id };

            if(search) {
                //build all conditions for every columns except created_at, updated_at and deleted_at
                let conditionForAllCol = addSearchCondForAllCol(db.tasks.rawAttributes, search, sequelize.Op);

                //adding extra condition as I also need to search based on the customer name too
                conditionForAllCol = [ 
                    ...conditionForAllCol,
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.col("customer.contact_person_name"), { [sequelize.Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" }),
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.col("customer.organization_name"), { [sequelize.Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" }),
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.col("task_status.name"), { [sequelize.Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" }),
                    sequelize.where(sequelize.col("priority.name"), { [sequelize.Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" }),
                ];

                //building the final condition for the search feature
                let searchCondition = { 
                    [sequelize.Op.or]: conditionForAllCol
                };
                
                condition = { ...condition, ...searchCondition };
            }

            if(!(task_status_id === null || task_status_id === undefined || task_status_id === "")) condition = { ...condition, task_status_id };

            if(!(priority_id === null || priority_id === undefined || priority_id === "")) condition = { ...condition, priority_id };

            //final query
            const instance = await db.tasks.findAll({
                limit: getPagination.limit,
                offset: getPagination.offset,
                where: {
                    [sequelize.Op.and]: [
                        {
                            "planned_date": {
                                [sequelize.Op.gt]: getDate.startDate,
                                [sequelize.Op.lte]: getDate.endDate
                            },
                            ...condition
                        }
                    ]
                },
                order: [["planned_date", "DESC"]],
                attributes: {
                    exclude: ["updated_at", "deleted_at"]
                },
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.customers,
                        require: false,
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.fences,
                        require: false,
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at", "status"]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.employees,
                        attributes: ["name", "personal_email"]
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.task_statuses,
                        attributes: ["name", "color_code"]
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.priorities,
                        attributes: ["name", "color_code"]
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.task_documents,
                        require: false,
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at", "status"]
                        },
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: db.medias,
                                attributes: {
                                    exclude: ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at", "status"]
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                model: db.document_categories,
                                attributes: {
                                    exclude: ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at", "status"]
                                },
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            });

            return instance;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    },

My requirement: Simply get data based on the search filter, sortname, sortvalue. Searching should happen for "contact_person_name, organization_name" col of customer table, based on "title" col of fence table, based on "name" col of task_statuses & priorities table.
Don't know where the issue is.
I am including the tables with required cols.
Based on the rawAttributes property given by sequelize, this will iterate all the cols of the tasks table for checking the searched value.
And additionally, I am adding customer, priority and task_status table's specific col using
sequelize.where(sequelize.col(....

This is working perfectly fine with "pagesize=&size=&" and giving proper results but not working for "pagesize=10&size=1&".

Try to use subQuery: false and indicate separate: true in model: db.task_documents include option

It worked. How you thought over it ? Just curious about the logic ... how you went through it ? @Anatoly

Using paging with nested model's conditions in the main where might not work because Sequelize by default trying to limit main model records by using a subquery (otherwise you will get wrong results).
So in order to make it work you need to turn off using a subquery by indicating subQuery: false in the main options and separate: true in the included model options to avoid incorrect results.
const instance = await db.tasks.findAll({
                limit: getPagination.limit,
                offset: getPagination.offset,
                subQuery: false, 
                where: {
                    [sequelize.Op.and]: [
                        {
                            "planned_date": {
                                [sequelize.Op.gt]: getDate.startDate,
                                [sequelize.Op.lte]: getDate.endDate
                            },
                            ...condition
                        }
                    ]
                },
                order: [["planned_date", "DESC"]],
                attributes: {
                    exclude: ["updated_at", "deleted_at"]
                },
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.customers,
                        require: false,
                        separate: true,
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: ["created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"]
                        }
                    },

If you don't indicate separate: true while turning off subQuery then the records from tasks will be multiplied by records from customers and if you, for instance, have 1 task with 10 customers and set limit to 10 then you will end up with only one task (because in SQL query you will get 10 first records with the same task and different customers).
Try to play with the generated SQLs to see the difference
